# How to read objects from JSON file and add its elements to JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, json, javafx

I am trying to read a file containing data in the form of JSON objects and want to display them in a javafx `TableView`.

FYI The data present in the file is in the following form.

```json
{"fileName":"compiler.xml","fileSize":"0.716796875  kb","destination":"Dev/SyncUtility/.idea/","userName":"itl@itl.com","uploadTime":"Jun 27,2018 15:59","fileType":"xml","status":"uploaded"}
```

Image shows the javafx tableview where I want to display the data

[image: This is the javafx tableview where i want to display the data]

As the table displays recent files I want to retrieve the data in reverse order and show them in the table.

Kindly suggest me how can I get this.

Comment: I suggest you get familiar with GSON or a similar library...

Comment: My advice is to search for JSON sort by value/key

Comment: Actually i am able to retrieve the data but unable to to know how to set values into table cells.

Comment: I assumed reversing the list, setting up the `TableView` and reversing the list once it's read is not a real issue. For the former another duplicate link could be added for the latter probably a tutorial would be better (Alternatively if you've created a suitable class for parsing teh JSON, and don't know how to set up the `TableColumn`s, the question would be narrow enough to be answerable here...).